# Why does Linux save %ebp when doing a context switch?

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel, x86

When doing a context switch, x86 Linux (very cleverly) avoids saving and restoring EAX, EBX, ECX, EDX, ESI, and EDI. Of course, the userland values are saved on the kernel stack when switching into kernel mode. But the values *in* the kernel code are not saved -- instead, GCC directives are used which tell the compiler not to keep any values which are needed in those registers at the point where the switch happens.

Naturally, ESP has to be saved and restored. But this is what I don't understand: before ESP is switched, EBP is pushed on the kernel stack. I would think that EBP was being used as a frame pointer, but in my kernel debugger, the values sure don't look like it:

```
(gdb) print $esp
$22 = (void *) 0xc0025ec0
(gdb) print $ebp
$23 = (void *) 0xcf827f3c
```

The difference is **way** too big for EBP to be a frame pointer here. A comment in the code says that "EBP is saved/restored explicitly for wchan access", but I'm searching the code and can't figure out how that is so. Google isn't helping either. Can some kernel wizard step in and help here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured it out. EBP *is* a frame pointer, but at the point that I checked its value, ESP had already been switched to the new process' kernel stack, but EBP had not yet been restored (so it still had the value from the previous process). Sorry!!

The reason for storing the frame pointer is so that others can determine where in the kernel code a process went to sleep. Among other things, this is used by `/proc/PID/wchan`, which prints the name of the kernel function which made a process sleep.

The code which checks this is as follows *(details removed for brevity)*:

```c
unsigned long get_wchan(struct task_struct *p)
{
    unsigned long sp, bp, ip;
    sp = p->thread.sp;
    bp = *(unsigned long *) sp;
    do {
        ip = *(unsigned long *) (bp+4);
        if (!in_sched_functions(ip))
            return ip;
        bp = *(unsigned long *) bp;
    } while (count++ < 16);
    return 0;
}
```

Since EBP is pushed right before switching kernel stacks, the stack pointer of a sleeping process will point to the saved EBP (frame pointer) value. That frame pointer points to the caller's saved frame pointer, which points to the previous caller's, which points to the previous caller's... in other words, the saved frame pointers form a linked list going back up the call stack.

The frame pointer is saved immediately on function entry, so the value just above it (4 bytes up) is the return address to the calling function.

The loop in `get_wchan` walks that "linked list" (`bp = *bp`), checking the return address above each saved frame pointer, until it finds an address within a function like `ep_poll` or `futex_wait_queue_me`.

`get_wchan` just returns an address inside a function; for display in `/proc`, `lookup_symbol_name` is used to convert that address into a function name.

Answer (score 3):

> The difference is way too big for EBP to be a frame pointer here.

Presumably you have compiled your kernel without frame pointers enabled. See the relevant config option:

```
config SCHED_OMIT_FRAME_POINTER
        def_bool y
        prompt "Single-depth WCHAN output"
        depends on X86
        ---help---
          Calculate simpler /proc/<PID>/wchan values. If this option
          is disabled then wchan values will recurse back to the
          caller function. This provides more accurate wchan values,
          at the expense of slightly more scheduling overhead.

          If in doubt, say "Y".
```

The function `get_wchan` will do a sanity check on the `ebp` value, and only use it if it seems to be a frame pointer.

I think it would be better to use the above config flag in both places, so that `ebp` would not be saved unnecessarily if it isn't a frame pointer, and also the `get_wchan` would not bother if we knew there wouldn't be a frame pointer. That said, saving/restoring `ebp` only adds a very little overhead, so it's not tragic.